# CreateFile & ReadFile

Tags: c, windows, winapi, wininet

How to open a filename given in Main's argv[] (say, D:\a.txt) by CreateFile API?

```
CreateFile( ReadBuffer, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
```

Comment: I suggest you do not try to write multi-language source files. Pick one of C or C++!

Comment: I apologise. Wud u ans my problem now? m new to this so plz overlook some errors

Comment: Why not use fopen and fread instead?

Comment: The [MSDN documentation for `CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) appears to be comprehensive. If you don't need all that complication, you can try the standard [`fopen()` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.5.3) instead: `fopen(argv[1], "w")`.

Comment: Yeah that wud be easy but I have to use CreateFile only.

Comment: You should explain what you are having a problem with exactly because as the question currently stands it would be valid to answer "HANDLE h = CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);" but since that is pretty obvious it must be something else you have a problem with.

Comment: My CreateFile method is in "Connect" function. So what I should pass to Connect from Main, so that it reads the argv[1] correctly. I am trying to pass it as main(int argc, char *argv[]) { connect(&argv); } Void Connect (char * arg) { CreateFile(...); } This code is showing error as to "none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that your problem is simply that you are trying to call a function like this

```
Connect(char *filename)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(filename, ...);
    ....
}
```

and don't know how to get hold of the first command-line argument. Do it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Incorrect number of arguments supplied\n.")
        return 1;
    }
    Connect(argv[1]);
    .....
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `argv` is an array containing `argc` items where each item is of type `char*`. So you simply want the item at index 1. The item at index 0 is the process name.

Comment: If the filename is containing a list of URLs, how sud i read the file line by line. Because if i read using while loop till it encounters a carriage return, I have to put all the InternetCrackUrl,InternetConnect, HttpOpenRequest, HttpSendRequest, HttpQueryInfo, all of them inside the while loop. Is there a better way to do this using "while" loop till carriage return logic only.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that would need to be asked as a new question, and you would need to show us some code. It's one question at a time and comments are for minor clarifications.

Comment: Oh...ok...I have posted it as a new question with some codings but I think its messy. Anyways have a look plz.

Comment: Whenever I CreateFile, the VB asks to debug in a new instance and breaks the debugging??????